# How to properly write JVM AES/CFB8 Encryption in Go

Tags: go, encryption, kotlin, aes

I wrote a little test in Kotlin to encrypt some text "Hello" using a Cipher instance with the algorithm "AES/CFB8/NoPadding". 
(minecraft stuff)

And I am now attempting to do the same in Go, however I am unable to produce the same result. All the different methods I have tried always produce something different.

These are the following threads/examples I've already looked through in order to get to this point.

1. [How to use rsa key pair for AES encryption and decryprion in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463221/how-to-use-rsa-key-pair-for-aes-encryption-and-decryprion-in-golang)
2. https://play.golang.org/p/77fRvrDa4A
3. [Decrypt in Golang what was encrypted in Python AES CFB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850023/decrypt-in-golang-what-was-encrypted-in-python-aes-cfb)
4. https://gist.github.com/temoto/5052503
5. [AES Encryption in Golang and Decryption in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210227/aes-encryption-in-golang-and-decryption-in-java)
6. [Different Results in Go and Pycrypto when using AES-CFB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897809/different-results-in-go-and-pycrypto-when-using-aes-cfb)

Kotlin Code:

```
enum class Mode(val mode: Int)
{

    ENCRYPT(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE),
    DECRYPT(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE),
}

fun createSecret(data: String): SecretKey
{
    return SecretKeySpec(data.toByteArray(), "AES")
}

fun newCipher(mode: Mode): Cipher
{
    val secret = createSecret("qwdhyte62kjneThg")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB8/NoPadding")
    cipher.init(mode.mode, secret, IvParameterSpec(secret.encoded))

    return cipher
}

fun runCipher(data: ByteArray, cipher: Cipher): ByteArray
{
    val output = ByteArray(data.size)

    cipher.update(data, 0, data.size, output)

    return output
}


fun main()
{
    val encrypter = newCipher(Mode.ENCRYPT)
    val decrypter = newCipher(Mode.DECRYPT)

    val iText = "Hello"
    val eText = runCipher(iText.toByteArray(), encrypter)
    val dText = runCipher(eText, decrypter)
    val oText = String(dText)


    println(iText)
    println(Arrays.toString(eText))
    println(Arrays.toString(dText))
    println(oText)
}
```

Go Code:

```golang
func TestCipher(t *testing.T) {

    secret := newSecret("qwdhyte62kjneThg")

    encrypter := newCipher(secret, ENCRYPT)
    decrypter := newCipher(secret, DECRYPT)

    iText := "Hello"
    eText := encrypter.run([]byte(iText))
    dText := decrypter.run(eText)
    oText := string(dText)

    fmt.Printf("%s\n%v\n%v\n%s\n", iText, eText, dText, oText)
}

type Mode int

const (
    ENCRYPT Mode = iota
    DECRYPT
)

type secret struct {
    Data []byte
}

type cipherInst struct {
    Data cipher2.Block
    Make cipher2.Stream
}

func newSecret(text string) *secret {
    return &secret{Data: []byte(text)}
}

func newCipher(data *secret, mode Mode) *cipherInst {
    cip, err := aes.NewCipher(data.Data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var stream cipher2.Stream

    if mode == ENCRYPT {
        stream = cipher2.NewCFBEncrypter(cip, data.Data)
    } else {
        stream = cipher2.NewCFBDecrypter(cip, data.Data)
    }

    return &cipherInst{Data: cip, Make: stream}
}

func (cipher *cipherInst) run(dataI []byte) []byte {

    out := make([]byte, len(dataI))
    cipher.Make.XORKeyStream(out, dataI)

    return out
}
```

Kotlin code produces the output:

```
Hello
[68, -97, 26, -50, 126]
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
Hello
```

However, the Go code produces the output:

```
Hello
[68 97 242 158 187]
[72 101 108 108 111]
Hello
```

At this point, this issue has pretty much halted the progress of the project I'm working on. Any information on what I'm missing or doing wrong would be helpful.

Comment: While I'm not 100% sure, I'd be willing to bet that `NewCFBEncrypter` / `NewCFBDecrypter` implement full-block CFB mode (i.e. CFB-128 for AES), not CFB-8. I don't know if there _is_ a built-in implementation of CFB-8 for Go; if not, you might have to implement it yourself using the raw AES block cipher directly (i.e. "in ECB mode").

Comment: In fact, [kostya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37234233) to the last question you linked to above seems to provide a CFB-8 implementation in Go.

Comment: I actually tried that as well, but it doesn't work... @IlmariKaronen 

Produces this:

Hello
[68 160 19 37 229]
[72 90 73 186 47]
HZI�/

Comment: Looks like there was a typo in the `XORKeyStream` function that caused decryption to fail. Funny that nobody had caught it before... Anyway, I just edited the answer to fix it, and [it seems to work fine now](https://repl.it/repls/GrowlingStarchyAbandonware).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different Results in Go and Pycrypto when using AES-CFB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897809/different-results-in-go-and-pycrypto-when-using-aes-cfb)

Comment: I linked that question in my post to show that I've seen it, and it didnt help.

Comment: Did you try it again after I fixed the typo in the answer I linked above?

Comment: Yes, I did, and it worked. Thank you. @IlmariKaronen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to implement CFB8 manually since the built in implementation defaults to CFB128.

Implementation created by kostya and fixed by Ilmari Karonen ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37234233/6114308)).